# How to show alert notification after mobile app was closed?

Tags: android, angularjs, popup, alert

I am a beginner in mobile app development. Now I'm using JavaScript.
Can I have some idea on how to create an `alert` that still can pop-up even though the app has been closed by user?
I planned to alert the user on *"taking medicine"* 1 day after he clicked *"I am sick"* in my app.

I have tried to use:

```
setTimeout(function(){ alert("taking medicine"); }, 10000);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: First you should get more familiar with the topic of background services and stuff of mobile app development and come back with some more concrete questions.

Comment: No javascript in a web page can perform any action after the page is closed (let alone a full day after.)

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing sounds like a push notification to me. You could configure your app with push notification services available in the market. Like the IBM Push notification service (https://www.ibm.com/cloud/push-notifications) or firebase cloud messaging.